# build Map of Maps in java 8 from list of Objects

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, maps

I need to convert a list of object into map of maps. I have tried to mock the problem statement in terms of student object. Any one to the rescue please. So teh problem is like below :

I have a list of Student object and I want to transform this into Map of Studentkey, Value is another map with key as DepartId Enum and value as count of departents. StudentKey is Object consist of studentId and Hno(some combination I need to use as a key to map). Departent is Enum. I have created it using java7, but not able to to so in Java 8. Can any one help please

```
public class Student {

    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private Department dept;
    private int hno;
    ...........
    }

public enum Department {
ARTS,SCIENCE,MATHS,MUSIC
}

public class StudentKey {
    private int Id;
    private int hno;
    .......
    }

    public class TestStudent {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Student st1= new Student(1, "Alex", Department.ARTS, 23);
            Student st2= new Student(1, "Alex", Department.ARTS, 23);
            Student st3= new Student(1, "Alex", Department.SCIENCE, 24);
            Student st4= new Student(1, "Alex", Department.SCIENCE, 24);
            Student st5= new Student(2, "John", Department.MUSIC, 25);
            Student st6= new Student(2, "John", Department.MATHS, 26);
            Student st7= new Student(2, "John", Department.MATHS, 26);
            Student st8= new Student(3, "Doe", Department.MUSIC, 25);
            Student st9= new Student(3, "Doe", Department.MATHS, 67);

            List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(st1);
            list.add(st2);
            list.add(st3);
            list.add(st4);
            list.add(st5);
            list.add(st6);
            list.add(st7);
            list.add(st8);
            list.add(st9);

            //buildMapinJava8(list);

            Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>> resultMap =buildMapinJava7(list);
            printMap(resultMap);
        }



        private static Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>>  buildMapinJava7(List<Student> list) {
            Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Student student : list) {
                StudentKey newKey = new StudentKey(student.getId(), student.getAge());
                Map<Department, Long> deptMap=  resultMap.get(newKey);
                if(deptMap==null){
                    deptMap = new HashMap<>();
                    resultMap.put(newKey, deptMap);
                }
                Long count =deptMap.get(student.getDept());
                count = count!=null?count:0;
                deptMap.put(student.getDept(), count+1);
            }
            return resultMap;
        }

        private static Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>>  buildMapinJava8(List<Student> list) {
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(new Function<Student, StudentKey>() {

                @Override
                public StudentKey apply(Student t) {

                    return new StudentKey(t.getId(), t.getAge());
                }
            }, new Function<Student, Map<Department, Long>>() {

                @Override
                public Map<Department, Long> apply(Student t) {
                    return null;//??? how to do here
                }
            }));

        }
private static void printMap(Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>> resultMap) {
            for (Entry<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.print(entry.getKey().getId()+" , "+entry.getKey().getAge()+" ");

                for(Entry<Department, Long> dept :entry.getValue().entrySet()){
                System.out.println("department : "+dept.getKey()+" :  "+dept.getValue());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don’t use `toMap`, use `groupingBy`. And fix the return type of `buildMapinJava8`…

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I fixed the return type. groupingBy should be used for innner map or for both. I new to Java 8 for excuse me for silly questions.

Comment: In this case, both, roughly like `groupingBy( t -> new StudentKey(t.getId(), t.getAge()),   groupingBy(Student::getDept, counting())   )`

Comment: Didn't quite get how do we implement counting?

Comment: The same way as `toMap` or `groupingBy` … [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--). Generally, using `import static` is a big win when using the `Collectors` class…

Comment: Thank you so much. It is solved. I have put it as separate answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Holger,It worked. here is my code.

```
private static Map<StudentKey, Map<Department, Long>> buildMapInJava8(List<Student> list) 
{
    Map<StudentKey,Map<Department,Long>> map = list.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> new StudentKey(t.getId(), t.getAge()),
               Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getDept, Collectors.counting())));

    return map;
}
```